# For given two integers A and B, find a pair of numbers X and Y such that A = X*Y and B = X xor Y

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I'm struggling with this problem I've found in a competitive programming book, but without a solution how to do it. 
For given two integers **A** and **B** (can fit in 64-bit integer type), where **A** is odd, find a pair of numbers X and Y such that **A**  = X*Y and **B** = X xor Y.
My approach was to list all divisors of A and try pairing numbers under sqrt(A) with numbers over sqrt(A) that multiply up to **A**  and see if their xor is equal to **B**. But I don't know if that's efficient enough.
What would be a good solution/algorithm to this problem?

Comment: It's weird to mix an integer operator and a bitwise operator. Is it really `X*Y` or `X&Y`?

Comment: It's multiplication. ( * )

Comment: Have you written any line of code already to solve this task? Which programming language do you intend to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple recursion that observes the rules we know: (1) the least significant bits of both X and Y are set since only odd multiplicands yield an odd multiple; (2) if we set X to have the highest set bit of B, Y cannot be greater than sqrt(A); and (3) set bits in X or Y according to the current bit in B.

The following Python code resulted in under 300 iterations for all but one of the random pairs I picked from Matt Timmermans' [example code](https://ideone.com/cEuHkQ). But the first one took 231,199 iterations :)

```py
from math import sqrt

def f(A, B):
  i = 64
  while not ((1<<i) & B):
    i = i - 1
  X = 1 | (1 << i)

  sqrtA = int(sqrt(A))

  j = 64
  while not ((1<<j) & sqrtA):
    j = j - 1

  if (j > i):
    i = j + 1

  memo = {"it": 0, "stop": False, "solution": []}

  def g(b, x, y):
    memo["it"] = memo["it"] + 1
    if memo["stop"]:
      return []

    if y > sqrtA or y * x > A:
      return []

    if b == 0:
      if x * y == A:
        memo["solution"].append((x, y))
        memo["stop"] = True
        return [(x, y)]
      else:
        return []

    bit = 1 << b

    if B & bit:
      return g(b - 1, x, y | bit) + g(b - 1, x | bit, y)
    else:
      return g(b - 1, x | bit, y | bit) + g(b - 1, x, y)

  g(i - 1, X, 1)
  return memo

vals = [
  (6872997084689100999, 2637233646), # 1048 checks with Matt's code
  (3461781732514363153, 262193934464), # 8756 checks with Matt's code
  (931590259044275343, 5343859294), # 4628 checks with Matt's code
  (2390503072583010999, 22219728382), # 5188 checks with Matt's code
  (412975927819062465, 9399702487040), # 8324 checks with Matt's code
  (9105477787064988985, 211755297373604352), # 3204 checks with Matt's code
  (4978113409908739575,67966612030), # 5232 checks with Matt's code
  (6175356111962773143,1264664368613886), # 3756 checks with Matt's code
  (648518352783802375, 6) # B smaller than sqrt(A)
]

for A, B in vals:
  memo = f(A, B)
  [(x, y)] = memo["solution"]
  print "x, y: %s, %s" % (x, y)
  print "A:   %s" % A
  print "x*y: %s" % (x * y)
  print "B:   %s" % B
  print "x^y: %s" % (x ^ y)
  print "%s iterations" % memo["it"]
  print ""
```

Output:

```
x, y: 4251585939, 1616572541
A:   6872997084689100999
x*y: 6872997084689100999
B:   2637233646
x^y: 2637233646
231199 iterations

x, y: 262180735447, 13203799
A:   3461781732514363153
x*y: 3461781732514363153
B:   262193934464
x^y: 262193934464
73 iterations

x, y: 5171068311, 180154313
A:   931590259044275343
x*y: 931590259044275343
B:   5343859294
x^y: 5343859294
257 iterations

x, y: 22180179939, 107776541
A:   2390503072583010999
x*y: 2390503072583010999
B:   22219728382
x^y: 22219728382
67 iterations

x, y: 9399702465439, 43935
A:   412975927819062465
x*y: 412975927819062465
B:   9399702487040
x^y: 9399702487040
85 iterations

x, y: 211755297373604395, 43
A:   9105477787064988985
x*y: 9105477787064988985
B:   211755297373604352
x^y: 211755297373604352
113 iterations

x, y: 68039759325, 73164771
A:   4978113409908739575
x*y: 4978113409908739575
B:   67966612030
x^y: 67966612030
69 iterations

x, y: 1264664368618221, 4883
A:   6175356111962773143
x*y: 6175356111962773143
B:   1264664368613886
x^y: 1264664368613886
99 iterations

x, y: 805306375, 805306369
A:   648518352783802375
x*y: 648518352783802375
B:   6
x^y: 6
59 iterations
```

Comment: This doesn't work when B < sqrt(A), e.g., when X==Y

Comment: X==Y is just the simplest example.  B can be any number < sqrt(A), like X=0x30000001, Y=0x30000007, A=X*Y, B=6

Comment: @MattTimmermans great catch. I've added handling and your example to the tests, which resolves in 59 iterations. Please let me know if you find other issues (or if this issue seems unresolved).

Comment: Interesting.  I was expecting that one to be expensive when you got it working.  We know that there are expensive cases from the 231199 one, but it's proving difficult to characterize them.  Anyway it looks like this works fine now.

Answer (score 10):

You know that at least one factor is <= sqrt(A). Let's make that one X.

The length of X in bits will be about half the length of A.

The upper bits of X, therefore -- the ones higher in value than sqrt(A) -- are all 0, and the corresponding bits in B must have the same value as the corresponding bits in Y.

Knowing the upper bits of Y gives you a pretty small range for the corresponding factor X = A/Y. Calculate Xmin and Xmax corresponding to the largest and smallest possible values for Y, respectively. Remember that Xmax must also be <= sqrt(A).

Then just try all the possible Xs between Xmin and Xmax. There won't be too many, so it won't take very long.

Comment: it's at most sqrt(A)/2 in the case where the upper bits of Y are all 0.   Fewer of them will be divisors, though.  If you're concerned about it, you can reduce the number to check by finding the divisors with Fermat's factorization method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method

Comment: This is a good insight (+1), but if we're talking about 64-bit integers, then sqrt(A)/2 can be more than a billion. It seems like that would still be too slow for a typical "competitive programming" situation. (Disclaimer: I've never done a programming competition, maybe I'm wrong about this.) Maybe there's a further insight that can be combined with this one somehow?

Comment: If you use fermat's method to find the possible divisors in the range, I think it reduces to sqrt(sqrt(A)), which is certainly OK

Answer (score 7):

The other straightforward way to solve this problem relies on the fact that the lower *n* bits of XY and X xor Y depend only on the lower *n* bits of X and Y.  Therefore, you can use the possible answers for the lower *n* bits to restrict the possible answers for the lower *n+1* bits, until you're done.

I've worked out that, unfortunately, there can be more than one possibility for a single *n*.  I don't know how often there will be a *lot* of possibilities, but it's probably not too often if at all, so this may be fine in a competitive context. Probabilistically, there will only be a few possibilities, since a solution for *n* bits will provide either 0 or two solutions for *n+1* bits, with equal probability.

It seems to work out pretty well for random input.  Here's the code I used to test it:

```
public static void solve(long A, long B)
{
    List<Long> sols = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Long> prevSols = new ArrayList<>();
    sols.add(0L);
    long tests=0;
    System.out.print("Solving "+A+","+B+"... ");
    for (long bit=1; (A/bit)>=bit; bit<<=1)
    {
        tests += sols.size();
        {
            List<Long> t = prevSols;
            prevSols = sols;
            sols = t;
        }
        final long mask = bit|(bit-1);
        sols.clear();
        for (long prevx : prevSols)
        {
            long prevy = (prevx^B) & mask;
            if ((((prevx*prevy)^A)&mask) == 0)
            {
                sols.add(prevx);
            }
            long x = prevx | bit;
            long y = (x^B)&mask;
            if ((((x*y)^A)&mask) == 0)
            {
                sols.add(x);
            }
        }
    }
    tests += sols.size();
    {
        List<Long> t = prevSols;
        prevSols = sols;
        sols = t;
    }
    sols.clear();
    for (long testx: prevSols)
    {
        if (A/testx >= testx)
        {
            long testy = B^testx;
            if (testx * testy == A)
            {
                sols.add(testx);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("" + tests + " checks -> X=" + sols);
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int range=Integer.MAX_VALUE; range > 32; range -= (range>>5))
    {
        long A = rand.nextLong() & Long.MAX_VALUE;
        long X = (rand.nextInt(range)) + 2L;
        X|=1;
        long Y = A/X;
        if (Y==0)
        {
            Y = rand.nextInt(65536);
        }
        Y|=1;
        solve(X*Y, X^Y);
    }
}
```

You can see the results here: https://ideone.com/cEuHkQ

Looks like it usually only takes a couple thousand checks.